# Search and sorted doesn't work in JqGrid (json)

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

I am working  with `JqGrid`.
I have some JSON from server

```
[{"Id":1,"Name":"product1","Price":234,"Size":"Small"},{"Id":18,"Name":"product2","Price":3242,"Size":"Large"}]
```

and Jquery code

```
$("#table").jqGrid({
            url: '@Url.Action("GetProductsAtJSON", "Product")',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Price', 'Size'],
            colModel: [
                { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 55, key: true, editable: true, editoptions: { readonly: true }, sortable: true, search:true },
                { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 150, editable: true, editoptions: { size: 25 }, editrules: { required: true }, search: true },
                { name: 'Price', index: 'Price', width: 100, align: 'center', editable: true, editoptions: { size: 25 }, editrules: { required: true, number: true, minValue: 1, maxValue: 10000 } },
                { name: 'Size', index: 'Size', width: 150, editable: true, edittype: "select", editoptions: { value: "0:Large;1:Medium;2:Small" } }
            ],
            pager: '#pager',
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'All product',
            height: '400',
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false,
                loadonce: true,
                id: "Id",
                root: function (obj) { return obj; },
                page: function (obj) { return 1; },
                total: function (obj) { return 1; },
                records: function (obj) { return obj.length; }
            }

        });
```

I have read the documentation and a lot of forums, but I don't understand why sorting and search doesn't work. Maybe my JSON format is incorrect and I must write `total` `page` `records`, but that's not working either. I use `key: true` from rows id, but it's not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: does it goes back to the action carrying the string?

Comment: in action i get string with sorted params... i don't know this..

How i can use clientside sorting? when i use datatype json sorting and search work in server side? i want simply sort)

Comment: basically JQGrid is a AJAX COntrolled and its not exactly a server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some small errors in your code:

- `loadonce: true` is jqGrid option and not the property of `jsonReader`
- You should use `sorttype` property for columns which content should be interpreted not as a text. For example you should add `sorttype: "integer"` to the definition of `'Id'` and `'Price'` columns
- I recommend you to consider whether the value `editoptions: {value: "0:Large;1:Medium;2:Small"}` is what you need. It will be important for edition only.
- I recommend you additionally to use `gridview: true` to improve performance of the grid, use `autoencode: true` to interpret the values in JSON input as textes instead of HTML fragments and use `height: 'auto'` to have better look of the grid.
- To have local searching of data you need either use [navGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:navigator#definition) or [filterToolbar](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching).

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/VladyslavZotov.htm) is an example of fixing of your code.

Comment: I use navGrid :)

Great work! Thanks for demo! it's correctly work)), i googling 4-5 hours...